# Sequence contains no matching element Error using Boolean

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
bool Postkey =
    statement
        .ThreadPostlist
        .First(x => x.ThreadKey == ThreadKey && x.ClassKey == classKey)
        .PostKey;
```

This Ling query is giving me "Sequence contains no matching element" but I know I can use `.FirstorDefault()`. When I use `.FirstorDefault()` it will return me `false`, the default value for `bool`, when there are no matching records.

But I get a "Object not set to an instance of an object" error. I need to check the `bool` for `null` with `.HasValue` and `.Value`. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You don't need to check the bool for null, you need to check the object for null before trying to reference the `.PostKey` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:-

```
bool? postkey = threadPostList
       .Where(x=>x.ThreadKey == threadKey && x.ClassKey == classKey)
       .Select(x => (bool?)x.PostKey)
       .DefaultIfEmpty()
       .First();
```

I think that better captures the intent of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a Question. I know .DefaultIfEmpty() will bring a element if the list is empty. So in case if the list is empty and it brings a element we want to select that by using .First()

Comment: Yes, if the list is empty it gets the default value for 'T' which is null for a 'bool?'. 'First()' is thus guaranteed to get at least one value.

Comment: Thank a lot for all of you really appreciate your time

Comment: THe code worked without using bool? as Postkey is not null. Is that ok when using DefaultIfEmpty(). It is hard to explain someone. I tried but they don't seem to get the logic. sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: THe code worked without using bool? as Postkey is not null. Is that ok when using DefaultIfEmpty(). It is hard to explain someone. I tried but they don't seem to get the logic. sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: THe code worked without using bool? as Postkey is not null. Is that ok when using DefaultIfEmpty(). It is hard to explain someone. I tried but they don't seem to get the logic. sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: If you omit the cast to 'bool?' it's an 'IEnumerable<bool>' so the default will be false if there are no elements. If you keep it it's an 'IEnumerable<bool?>' which has a default value of null. So it depends - do you want a null for no matching element or false?

Comment: Thanks I got it . will use Ienumerable <bool > and get False and .First() will get that value.

Comment: Thanks I got it . will use Ienumerable <bool > and get False and .First() will get that value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use a nullable bool to solve this:

```
bool? postKey = null;
// This can be null
var post = statement.ThreadPostlist.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ThreadKey == ThreadKey  && x.ClassKey == classKey);
if (post != null) {
    postKey = post.PostKey;
}
// Now that you have your nullable postKey, here is how to use it:
if (postKey.hasValue) {
    // Here is the regular bool, not a nullable one
    bool postKeyVal = postKey.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but i want to ask you do we need to use NULLABLE BOOL for postkey. (bool? postkey = null ) I am not looking for the value i am just trying to get the PostKey from a list where Postkey is a BOOL type.  .

Comment: @user3920526 Although `Postkey` is a regular `BOOL` type, not a nullable, the fact that there may be no record makes nullable a valid choice. You can avoid nullable if it is possible to use a single `if`, and put all code that uses `postKey` inside the `if (post != null)` conditional. Then you could move `bool? postKey` into the `if`, and replace with non-nullable `bool postKey = post.PostKey;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat a `null` value as false (and don't want to use a nullable bool), you could just check if the resulting post is null before referencing the `.PostKey` property, like this:

```
var threadPost = statement.ThreadPostlist.FirstOrDefault(x => 
    x.ThreadKey == ThreadKey && x.ClassKey == classKey);

bool PostKey = threadPost != null && threadPost.PostKey;
```

Or, a longer form would be:

```
bool PostKey;

if (threadPost != null)
{
    PostKey = threadPost.PostKey;
{
else
{
    PostKey = false;
}
```

Comment: I have a question. The way you assigned the Postkey = threadPost !=null && threadpost.PostKey;  works. But if i put a IF CLAUSE  if ( threadPost !=null ) then when i assign value to PostKey. I am using it somewhere else  it throws an Error. PostKey does not exist in current context. YOu have clue. It only works how you checked for null but not with a if clause check it will throw an error if i try to use the value somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but I added a different example to see if that's what you're talking about... The reason my 'short form' works is that Boolean evaluations are performed left-to-right, and, when all the expressions are ANDed (`&&`), the evaluation is short-circuited as soon as an expression evaluates to `false`. So if `threadPost == null`, then there is never an attempt to call `threadPost.PostKey`.

Comment: Just re-read your comment. If you are getting `PostKey does not exist in current context`, then that is a different issue. You should probably post a new question for that one if you can't resolve it, but it sounds like you're trying to reference the variable when it's out of scope.